# Fabric js create a group of clip masks

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, mask, clip

I need help with fabric js 
I want to create a group of clips, the group can have many clips next to each other. Each clip can have an image inside it.

similar to the grid function in [canva](https://www.canva.com/)
[group of 2 clip masks with space between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WINwO.png)

this is what I have so far it displays in a very weird shape 
http://jsfiddle.net/SallyMagdyTadros/ZxYCP/1467/

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
var img01URL = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
(function() {
 var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    var img2;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {
        img2 = img.scale(0.5).set({
            left: 100,
            top: 0,
            clipTo: function(ctx) {
                ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 200);

            }
        });
    });
    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 
    function(img) {
        img.scale(0.5).set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            clipTo: function(ctx) {
                     ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 100);
                }
        });

        var group = new fabric.Group([img, img2], {

        });
        group.left = 0;
        group.top = 0;
        canvas.add(group);
       });
       })();
```

Comment: Can we upgrade to fabricjs 2 latest? 1.4.8 was so old i do not remember what features had.

Comment: updated now to the latest version 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/1625/

Comment: So my first question, is, being a group, what is the point of clipping? you want the picture to slide in a window and be clipped? Once they are grouped you cannot really move them. What the final result look like and how it behaves to the user

Comment: I want to click on a shape that creates multi placeholders
that I can later drag images on each placeholder and it would clip the image to the shape? is it clear?
it's similar to the grid and frame in canva 
https://www.canva.com/design/DAA7XyqmXto/remix?minichallenge

Comment: I did not disappear. There is nothing builtin to do this, i m search an possible way that does not requiring coding for a week for me.

Comment: Thank you for putting effort into answering my question 
it would definitely be a great plus to the library.
Please tell me if u come up with something and I'll do the same.

Comment: This is really an application use case and should be in no way part of the library, unless the libray will become a editor only thing. It would make a GREAT tutorial anyway

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi can we achieve the needed result using masks? 
but I can't control the group once I mask an image